# Automate Type Conversion in Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'd like to use the hibernate criteria api on my `Order` entity in the following way:

```
Restrictions.eq("orderDate", new org.joda.time.DateTime());
```

However my `Order` entity uses the Java 8 time api:

```
class Order {
    java.time.ZonedDateTime orderDate;
}
```

With the code as it stands Hibernate tries to cast the joda `DateTime` to the java `ZonedDateTime`, which inevitably fails.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to inform hibernate how to convert any occurrences of `DateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` without having to make a change to the `Restrictions.eq` call?

Comment: Why are you mixing JodaTime and Java 8 DataTime API? That doesn't make sense

Comment: I think OP got old API and now he tries to migrate that to Java8 and dont want to refactor billions of Restiction entries - guess. But still, I would drop joda and use Java8 time API

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/34612650/1527544

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes that's exactly right, I'm currently migrating away from joda and there's a huge amount of work to refactor all Restrictions. Thanks for the suggestion of `hibernate-java8`, I've just had a look in to it and unfortunately that was for hibernate <5.2 before it supported java 8 in `hibernate-core` and therefore not related to joda