# Spring MVC - Failure Creating a SessionFactory Bean (Invocation of init method failed) [java.lang.AbstractMethodError]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm facing an AbstractMethodError when creating a simple Spring MVC application, running the following versions:

Hibernate - 5.4.2.Final
Spring - 5.1.6.RELEASE
Java - 11.0.9

I believe the problem is the way I'm wiring between my Repository, Service, and the Application Context.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/MyCVOnline/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

The entire code is in my GitHub
https://github.com/Diego-Oviedo/JobBoardWithSpring

Any kind of help will be very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to guess bug with your log. Request you to update full log report so that we can answer in proper way.

Things which I observed with your log is given below:---

you should not pass "SessionFactory" as argument just remove n check whether working or not.

In your code:-----

```
@Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
         HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
         = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

But it should be something like this:----

```
@Bean
        @Autowired
        public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
             HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
             = new HibernateTransactionManager();
           transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the Hibernate version I used; as I'm running Hibernate 5, several classes and dependencies are no longer supported such as `org.jadira.usertype` , `joda-time`, `Query` as a class, or `SetString()` as a method.

References:

[Resolving java.lang.AbstractMethodError, Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678273/resolving-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-error-creating-bean-with-name-entityma/47678519)

[Migrating To Hibernate 5 from 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732785/migrating-to-hibernate-5-from-3)

The following dependency was added,

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

---

I removed the `org.jadira.usertype` , `joda-time` dependencies from my pom.xml . However, my POJOS/Spring Beans were designed to consume those dependencies, i.e. with the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICANTS_EDUCATION")
public class ApplicantEducation implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "EDUCATION_TITLE")
private String educationTitle;

@Column(name = "SCHOOL_NAME")
private String schoolName;

@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "DD/MM/YYYY")
@Column(name = "START_DATE", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private String startDate;
```

The Annotation `@Type` and the object type were changed

```
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "DD/MM/YYYY")
@Column(name = "START_DATE", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")
private LocalDateTime startDate;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "DD/MM/YYYY")
@Column(name = "END_DATE")
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.LocalDateTimeType")
private LocalDateTime endDate;
```